# Rails - undefined local variable or method `timetable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive been working on a Rails project. Only started learning rails coming from a Java background

Im creating a Timetable model and controller where users can upload their timetables to the website.

The error i get it

```
undefined local variable or method `timetable' for #<#<Class:0x007fcde39dcbd8>:0x007fcde38b0ea8>
```

**Timetable Controller**

```
    class TimetablesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @timetables = Timetable.all
  end

  def new
    @timetable = Timetable.new
  end

  def create
    @timetable = Timetable.new(timetable_params)

    if @timetable.save
      redirect_to timetable_path, notice: "The resume #{@timetable.name} has been uploaded."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @timetable = Timetable.find(params[:id])
    @timetable.destroy
    redirect_to timetables_path, notice:  "The timetable #{@timetable.name} has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def timetable_params
    params.require(:timetable).permit(:name, :attachment)
  end
end
```

**Timetable Index**

```
    <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<br />
<%= link_to "New Timetable", new_timetable_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<br />
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Download Link</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @timetables.each do |resume| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= timetable.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Download Resume", timetable.attachment_url %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Delete",  timetable, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{timetable.name}?" %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Relavent Routes Entry**

```
resources :timetables, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

I assume my problem is scope but im not too familiar with rails at this stage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index action you define your timetable collection like so:

```
@timetables = Timetable.all
```

To use that instance variable in your view you iterate through your timetables naming each one `resume`. I guess you want it to be timetable:

```
<% @timetables.each do |timetable| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= timetable.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Download Resume", timetable.attachment_url %></td>
    <td><%= button_to "Delete",  timetable, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{timetable.name}?" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly. Thanks. I need to wait 5 mins to accept as correct answer apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change resume into timetable because there is no timetable variable.

```
<% @timetables.each do |timetable| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= timetable.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Download Resume", timetable.attachment_url %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Delete",  timetable, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{timetable.name}?" %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: An oversight on my part but Resume is only mentioned in Strings.

Comment: Actually sorry my mistake again. I see it now. Thanks

Comment: I mean `resume` in looping but it's okay. I hope it helps you.